# Why is xcode(4) so slow to dismiss errors I've already fixed?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

So I hit Cmd+B and xcode throws all these errors and warnings at me. But after I fix them, xcode is sometimes slow to catch on, often requiring another Cmd+B on my part to nudge it to recheck the file. Is there a setting somewhere I can toggle to make xcode recheck for errors more aggressively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is xcode(4) so slow to dismiss errors in code I've already fixed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506884/why-is-xcode4-so-slow-to-dismiss-errors-in-code-ive-already-fixed)

Comment: Only possible duplicate? It was posted at the same time by the same person, and the content of that question was exactly the same as this but posted 3 times until I removed the last two.

Comment: @ugho: it's an automatically generated comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's still room for improvement on the things that cause Xcode to retry your code. One thing I've noticed is that if you change something in a header than navigate back to the implementation, it quite often won't detect the fix until you force a build (or run it, which builds first).

The workaround? Save (Cmd-S) the file before navigating away from it or save all files (Cmd-Opt-S) if you've fixed several problems across several files.

The long-term solution? File bug reports at http://bugreporter.apple.com